# Webpack bundle and minify all javascript file in directory not working

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to bundle and minify 5 javascript files in an assets/ directory.

I have the following setup but it is not working for me.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle": ".assets/*",

  },

  output: {
    path: "./dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      include: /\.js$/,
      minimize: true
    })
  ]
};
```

Not sure if the wildcard operator does what I think it does.

Comment: Do any of these files in assets directory import each other?

Comment: Let's assume for the moment that they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack does not support the wilcard operator as you can see in this issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/370

However, you can try the alternative solutions mentioned there, this should be what you want (if you are willing to install the glob dependency):

```
var glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle": glob.sync("./assets/*"),
  },
```

(*) You had a typo in the config also, `.assets/*` should be `./assets/*`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at webpack's docs, I don't think you can specify a pattern for the string like that, I think it instead expects a path to the file. You could pass an array of the filenames in assets, or you could pass a function that returns the files in the folder:

```
entry: ['./assets/asset1.js', './assets/asset2.js' ...]
```

or

```
entry: () => fs.readdirSync('./assets')
```

There are more options, but these two seem the simplest.

***However***, if they can't all be reached through a single entrypoint, I don't think you can include multiple entrypoints in one single output file. Rather, they would each have to be outputted into their own bundle.

Answer (score -1):

Will this work for you?

```
"entry": "assets/index.js"
```

I'm wondering if the entry should just be one file that imports the others.

Comment: Look at the comment on the original post which specifically says that OP is assuming that they don't import each other